# Should I use nested if .. else statements for a series of less than comparisons in PHP

Tags: php

I need to do a series of comparisons with an integer in PHP, returning a different string depending on the result and I am wondering if an if..else block is the most elegant method. The code looks like:

```
if( $total < 10000 ) {
  return 'string A';
} elseif( $total < 20000 ) {
  return 'string B';
} elseif( $total < 30000 ) {
  return 'string C';
} elseif( $total < 40000 ) {
  return 'string D';
} elseif( $total < 50000 ) {
  return 'string E';
}
```

Which works, I just don't think it's very pretty. If I was doing equality checks then I would use a switch block.

Comment: Switch can do comparison like above: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#93342   just an fyi :)

Comment: @premiso: No, `switch` does not work that way. `$totaltime < 1` is returning a boolean value that is then compared to `$totaltime`.

Comment: Interesting. Never really tried it, but makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. So doing a `switch(1)` instead of the `switch($totaltime)` would be the more "correct" way of doing it. (Not saying you should do it that way) just clarifying.

Comment: Just for fun, this could be done in 1 line whenever the next version of PHP is released (5.4 or 6):

    return 'string '.range('A','E')[floor($total/10000)];

Answer (score 7):

You could use an array like this (assuming that `$total` is always positive):

```
$results = array('string A', 'string B', 'string C', 'string D', 'string E');
$index = floor($total / 10000);
if ($index < 5) return $results[$index];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of (just too slow). +1

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a switch-case statement as suggested in one of the comments you will have to write it like this:

```
switch(true) {
  case ($total < 10000): return 'string A';
  case ($total < 20000): return 'string B';
  case ($total < 30000): return 'string C';
  case ($total < 40000): return 'string D';
  case ($total < 50000): return 'string E';
}
```

Each case will be evaluated as true|false, and as soon as you script hits what it is looking for `true` it will return the corresponding string.

It will probably not be more efficient than your original code, but it is easier to read...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement like:

```
switch (round($total / 10000)) {
    case 0: //0xxxx
        break;
    case 1: //1xxxx
        break;
    case 2: //2xxxx
        break;
    case 3: //3xxxx
        break;
    ...
}
```

I'm not a PHP programmer so syntax may be wrong.

Comment: This would only work with numbers that divide to whole numbers; you'd need to use `round()`.

Comment: There you go :) I guess PHP converts it to a real/float of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility), though this could be somewhat overengieered for your UseCase.

Answer (score 0):

From the code-reusing pov, op's style is quite satisfactory. It's easy to comprehend and modify. But, yeah, for "elegance", Gumbo's snippet is the way to go.

```
    if ($total < 10000) { return 'string A'; } 
elseif ($total < 20000) { return 'string B'; } 
elseif ($total < 30000) { return 'string C'; } 
elseif ($total < 40000) { return 'string D'; } 
elseif ($total < 50000) { return 'string E'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work in cases where you are not returning based on the result, or when you need to do more than one operation, but with the example you provided, you wouldn't even need the else if's or a switch, it could just be:

```
if ($total < 10000) return 'A';
if ($total < 20000) return 'B';
if ($total < 30000) return 'C';
if ($total < 40000) return 'D';
if ($total < 50000) return 'E';
```